# merge 3 array and join field in lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Please help me, I want merge difference 3 arrays to join with field **_id**. My arrays like that. I try to merge all array by **_id** but still work wrong and i have no idea please.

```
//array 1
let  inventory =[ 
 { _id: '0001',
   itemId: '0001',
   onHandQty:  70,
   avgCost: 9,
   balanceAmount: 630,
 },
 { _id: '0002',
   itemId: '0002',
   onHandQty: 70,
   avgCost: 5,
   balanceAmount: 350,
 }
]
//array 2
let  po =[
 {
   _id : "0002",    
   onHandPO : 10
 },
 {
   _id : "0001",    
   onHandPO : 20
 }
]

//array 3
let  so =[
 {     
  _id: "0001",  
  onHandSO: 2
 },
 {
  _id: "0003",  
  onHandSO: 1
 }
]
```

I want all array join by _id to become one array like that. This result I need.

```
let  inventory =[ 
 { _id: '0001',
   itemId: '0001',
   onHandQty:  70,
   avgCost: 9,
   balanceAmount: 630,
   onHandPO : 20,
   onHandSO: 2
 },
 { _id: '0002',
   itemId: '0002',
   onHandQty: 70,
   avgCost: 5,
   balanceAmount: 350,
   onHandPO : 10
 },
 { _id: '0003',
   itemId: '0002',
   onHandQty: 0,
   avgCost: 0,
   balanceAmount: 0,
   onHandPO : 0
   onHandSO: 1
 }
]
```

Comment: at least, you could try something and present the result. actually it is to broad.

Comment: This my result:  **let  test =[ 
 { _id: '0001',
   itemId: '0001',
   onHandQty:  70,
   avgCost: 9,
   balanceAmount: 630,
   onHandPO : 20,
   onHandSO: 2
 },
 { _id: '0002',
   itemId: '0002',
   onHandQty: 70,
   avgCost: 5,
   balanceAmount: 350,
   onHandPO : 10
 },
 { _id: '0003',
   itemId: '0002',
   onHandQty: 0,
   avgCost: 0,
   balanceAmount: 0,
   onHandPO : 0
   onHandSO: 1
 }
]**

Comment: How obhect wid `_id:0003` is getting rest of the values?

Comment: result : _id:'0003'  like that `[
 {     
  _id: "0001",  
  onHandSO: 2
 },
 {
  _id: "0003",  
  onHandSO: 1
 }
]`

Comment: I want result  `let  result =[ 
 { _id: '0001',
   itemId: '0001',
   onHandQty:  70,
   avgCost: 9,
   balanceAmount: 630,
   onHandPO : 20,
   onHandSO: 2
 },
 { _id: '0002',
   itemId: '0002',
   onHandQty: 70,
   avgCost: 5,
   balanceAmount: 350,
   onHandPO : 10
 },
 { _id: '0003',
   itemId: '0002',
   onHandQty: 0,
   avgCost: 0,
   balanceAmount: 0,
   onHandPO : 0
   onHandSO: 1
 }
]`

Comment: Add the results and code to the question not in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flat all array, group them by the common value and assign all values to a single object. Then get the result.

```js
var inventory = [{ _id: '0001', itemId: '0001', onHandQty: 70, avgCost: 9, balanceAmount: 630 }, { _id: '0002', itemId: '0002', onHandQty: 70, avgCost: 5, balanceAmount: 350 }],
    po = [{ _id: "0002", onHandPO: 10 }, { _id: "0001", onHandPO: 20 }],
    so = [{ _id: "0001", onHandSO: 2 }, { _id: "0003", onHandSO: 1 }],
    result = _([inventory, po, so])
        .flatten()
        .groupBy('_id')
        .map(values => _.assign({}, ...values))
        .value();

console.log(_.sumBy(result, 'onHandSO')); // total of onHandSO 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can I sum field `total+=onHandSo`